# Remove All Pandas Rows Except Each Column Closest The The Start of Hour

Tags: pandas

I have a frame, df:

```
Date A B C  
x    1 1 1
y    1 1 1
z    1 1 1
```

The "Date" column is my index, and all timestamps are random times down to the second level. I want to remove all rows in the dataframe, except for the row that is the closest to the start of a new hour.

For example, if 12/15/16 15:16:12 is the earliest row in hour 15 of that date, I want every other row with a time stamp greater than that stamp to be deleted. I then want the process repeated for the next hour, and so on.

Is this possible in a fast manner in pandas?

Thanks

Comment: What if `12/15/16 14:59:04` is closer to the `15:00:00` hour?  Do you only want the closest time that is greater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `groupby` and `head` after `sort_index`

```
df.sort_index().groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')).head(1)
Out[83]: 
                     A 
Date                   
2016-12-15 15:16:12   1
```

Data input

```
df
Out[84]: 
                     A 
Date                   
2016-12-15 15:16:12   1
2016-12-15 15:19:12   1
2016-12-15 15:56:12   1
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Index was already sorted by time as well so did not need to do that. Thank you.

Comment: What happened to classic Wen... `df.sort_index().pipe(lambda d: d[~d.index.floor('H').duplicated()])`

Comment: @piRSquared this is great Sir